# Prolog- Convert a matrix to a list with indices

Tags: list, matrix, prolog

I have a Matrix like this:

```
[[0,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]]
```

and I need a list that saves the index when a row is not `[0,0,0]`. 
So the result in my example should be:

```
[2,3,4,5,7,8]
```

I have problems to program recursive in Prolog because i haven`t really figured out how it works.

Would it maybe help to first convert the matrix into a vector? It doesn't matter if its `[1,0,0]` or `[0,1,0]`. The only thing that is important is that it's not `[0,0,0]`.

Comment: Formatted code to code style instead of quote style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to describe a list, you could opt to use DCGs. They usually yield quite easily readable code:

```
matrix_indices(M,I) :-
   phrase(indices(M,0),I).    % the list I is described by the DCG indices//2

indices([],_) -->             % if M is empty
   [].                        % I is empty too
indices([[0,0,0]|Ls],I0) -->  % if the head of M is [0,0,0]
   {I1 is I0+1},              % the current index is calculated but is not in I
   indices(Ls,I1).            % the same holds for the tail
indices([L|Ls],I0) -->        % if the head of the list
   {dif(L,[0,0,0])},          % differs from [0,0,0]
   {I1 is I0+1},              % the current index is calculated              
   [I1],                      % and is in the list I
   indices(Ls,I1).            % the same holds for the tail
```

Note that the goals enclosed in braces are normal Prolog-goals. If you query this predicate with your given example you get the desired solution:

```
   ?- matrix_indices([[0,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]],I).
I = [2,3,4,5,7,8] ? ;
no
```

You can also use the predicate in the other direction but you have to ask for a concrete length or prefix a goal `length(M,_)`to prevent the predicate from looping. For example the query...

```
   ?- length(M,_), matrix_indices(M,[2,3,4,5,7,8]).
M = [[0,0,0],_A,_B,_C,_D,[0,0,0],_E,_F],
dif(_A,[0,0,0]),
dif(_B,[0,0,0]),
dif(_C,[0,0,0]),
dif(_D,[0,0,0]),
dif(_E,[0,0,0]),
dif(_F,[0,0,0]) ? ;
M = [[0,0,0],_A,_B,_C,_D,[0,0,0],_E,_F,[0,0,0]],
dif(_A,[0,0,0]),
dif(_B,[0,0,0]),
dif(_C,[0,0,0]),
dif(_D,[0,0,0]),
dif(_E,[0,0,0]),
dif(_F,[0,0,0]) ? ;
M = [[0,0,0],_A,_B,_C,_D,[0,0,0],_E,_F,[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
dif(_A,[0,0,0]),
dif(_B,[0,0,0]),
dif(_C,[0,0,0]),
dif(_D,[0,0,0]),
dif(_E,[0,0,0]),
dif(_F,[0,0,0]) ? 
.
.
.
```

... yields infinitely many answers as expected.

Answer (score 3):

How I would solve using findall/3 and nth1/3:

```
?- M = [[0,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]],
   findall(I, (nth1(I,M,E), E\=[0,0,0]), L).
L = [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8]
```